# Huygen's Principle, Snell's law and velocity of light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, geometric-optics, huygens-principle

Can you deduce Snell's law from Huygen's Principle without knowing in which medium the velocity is going to less? Of all the derivations I have seen of Snell's law using Huygen's Principle (light going from rarer to denser medium with $v1$ and $v2$ velocities respectively), they assume $v2 < v1$ and hence a smaller circle is drawn in denser medium and Snell's law follow immediately. I get that. What I want to know is what if you didn’t know that velocity is less in denser medium can you still derive Snell's law from Huygen's principle? I remember reading somewhere that Huygen's proved that velocity is less in denser medium. I was wondering if someone could show me how.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is what if you didn’t know that velocity is less
>   in denser medium can you still derive Snell's law from Huygens
>   principle?

No. It is impossible to predict the behavior of the wave front crossing the boundary between two media and, therefore, the angle of refraction, essential to Snell's law, by just applying Huygens principle: you need to know the ratio of velocities or some other additional information describing the two media.

> I remember reading somewhere that Huygens proved that velocity is
>   less in denser medium.

He must have relied on some additional information - not just Huygens principle.

For instance, if he observed refraction and applied Huygens principle, he could conclude that the velocity in the two media was different.